# Url Encoding in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hey guys I need to encode the URL of my application.My url looks as follows:
http://localhost:22039/Questionnaire/RenderQuestion?section=2&questionnaireId=2&assignmentId=3&ReadOnly=0

Among above i need to hide section number and all remaining ids.Or i need to replace those actual data with some others rough values.

So, any idea about this url encoding will be highly appreciated.

Comment: (Telepathic guess) Change your HTML form containing those parameters by adding `method="post"` attribute to `<form>` element? P.S. It's not called 'encoding'. 'URL encoding' means representing non-alpanumeric chars with respective numeric values, like changing space " " to "%20" in URLs